# How to dynamically change a button text

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to work around a webview issue on Android devices using Select drop down menus, using instead radio buttons in a popup to make user selections

What I need though is for the button text to change according to the selection the user has made. I've put togetaher a Fiddle of what I thought would work, but it's not playing ball, and I was wondering if any wiser heads out there could offer some advice.

Fiddle here;
http://jsfiddle.net/vinomarky/gEXhD/

Note: I've currently added some alerts in there when the javascripts fire, but they are not firing, and am not sure why not.

Question 1:
How to change the button text to match the user selection

Question 2:
How to make the radio selection minimize as soon as a user has made a selection, without having to click off the radio

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can use jquery `click` event instead of using `onclick` attribute
- because  you use jquery mobile ui, to change button text you should change button text container value not `pressure_cands` itself
- and to hide popup screen when an item selected call `click` event of `popupBasic-screen` div

  ```
  $('#updown1').click(function(){
      // to change button label
      $('#pressure_cands .ui-btn-text').html('THP');
      // call popupBasic-screen click event to hide popup menu
      $('#popupBasic-screen').click();
  });
  $('#updown2').click(function(){
      // to change button label
      $('#pressure_cands .ui-btn-text').html('FBHP');
      // call popupBasic-screen click event to hide popup menu
      $('#popupBasic-screen').click();
  });​
  ```

Comment: So I pasted the script in the html body inline, and the action in the background seems to be happening, as does the correct behaviour of the box disappearing when you click it, but the button text is not updating. Any suggestions to troubleshoot? The Fiddle worked just fine....

Comment: you omit space between `#pressure_cands` and `.ui-btn-text`. new fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/farnabaz/w58ya/